# Verification of $(m+1)| \binom{2m}{m}$ and interpretation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

While examining the central binomial coefficients, I noticed that $(m+1)$ always seemed to divide $\binom{2m}{m}$. I would like to confirm that a short proof I have found, using Hall's theorem, is correct.

If the proof (or, at least, the result) is correct, could someone provide a combinatorial explanation for why this is true? Why would $(m+1)$ divide the number of $m$-subsets of a set of size $2m$?

---

**Lemma**: let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, the set $\{2,...,m\}$ contains (at least) as many multiples of $n$ as $\{m+2, ..., 2m\}$.

**Proof of lemma**: WLOG $1 < n < m$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ be the number of multiples of $n$ in $\{2,...,m\}$ i.e. $kn < m < (k+1)n$. If $(k+1)n = m+1$, then $$\{(k+1)n,...,(2k+1)n\} \subseteq \{(m+2),...2m\}$$ since $kn + (k+1)n <  2m+1$.

Otherwise, $\{(k+1)n,...,2kn\} \subseteq \{(m+2),...2m\}$. $\square$

---

**Proposition**: $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}, (m+1) | \binom{2m}{m}$.

**Proof of proposition**:

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $v_p(n)$ denote the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$. Let $p$ be a (fixed) prime dividing $m$.

Construct a bipartite graph $G$ with $V = X \cup Y$, where $X = \{2, ..., m\}$, $Y = \{(m+2), ..., 2m\}$ and $x \sim y$ if and only if $v_p(x) \le v_p(y)$ ($x\in X, y \in Y$).

We show that $G$ satisifies Hall's condition i.e. $|N(A)| \ge |A|, \; \forall A \subseteq X$.

Let $A \subseteq X$, and let: $$v = \min_{x \in A} v_p(x)$$

Then, note that $$N(A) = \Big\{ y \in \{(m+2), ..., 2m\} \; : \; p^v | y \Big\}$$ while

$$A \subseteq \Big\{ x \in \{2, ..., m\} \; : \; p^v | x \Big\}$$

By the lemma applied to $n = p^v$, $|N(A)| \ge |A|$. Hence, by Hall's theorem, there exists a matching. By pairing the numbers in this way, we deduce that:

$$v_p\Big( (m+2) \cdots (2m) \Big) - v_p \Big( (2) \cdots (m) \Big) \ge 0$$

Hence, $$p^k \Big| (m+1) \implies p^k \Bigg| \binom{2m}{m} = (m+1)\frac{(m+2) \cdots (2m)}{(2) \cdots (m)} $$

But $p$ was arbitrary so we deduce that $(m+1) \Big| \binom{2m}{m}$. $\square$

---

Thanks to Michael Lugo who has identified the sequence $C_m = \frac{1}{m+1} \binom{2m}{m}$ as the Catalan numbers. There is a much easier proof that $C_m \in \mathbb{N}$; note that $C_m = \binom{2m}{m} - \binom{2m}{m+1}$. I am still interested to know if the proof above is correct.

Comment: In fact ${2m \choose m}/(m+1)$ is the $m$th Catalan number.  The Catalan numbers have many combinatorial interpretations so there are probably many nice combinatorial explanations for your question.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Wow, I have no idea how I didn't find that out while searching. I guess it's good because otherwise I would never have bothered to prove this :-) Do you know if $\binom{2m}{m} / (2m-1)$ is also always integral?

Comment: It's hard to search; I didn't remember it until I computed the first few values and realized the sequence looked familiar.

Comment: Let $C_m = {2m \choose m}/(m+1)$ be the Catalan numbers, and let $D_m = {2m \choose m}/(2m-1)$. Then $D_m = 2 C_{m-1}$ by some algebra too annoying to fit into this comment box.  In particular this means $D_m$ is also always integral.

Answer (score 2):

> could someone provide a combinatorial explanation for why this is true? Why would $(m+1)$ divide the number of $m$-subsets of a set of size $2m$?

As Michael Lugo says, the quotient is a Catalan number. You can write down a direct combinatorial proof that the quotient is an integer (without any further binomial coefficient manipulations) using a result called Raney's lemma. [Here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/update-and-the-combinatorics-of-quintic-equations/) you can see the result stated (without being named because I forgot the name for awhile) and used to prove the more general fact that $(k-1)m + 1$ divides ${km \choose m}$ (the quotient is a generalization of the Catalan numbers).

Comment: " (the quotient is a generalization of the Catalan numbers) " specifically it's a Fuss-Catalan number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuss%E2%80%93Catalan_number